# How to configure a shortcut title through Win API

Tags: c++, winapi, shortcut, shortcut-file

I create a shortcut by using the Win32 API. This is a COM API whose object model is accessable through IShellLink. I write in C++. Could you please share any ideas on how I can configure a shortcut title that appears right under the shortcut using this API?

Comment: What title are you referring to?

Comment: A shortcut's display name is a name of its link file (without extension). Thanks, guys.

Comment: @Vitaly You've asked 16 questions and accepted no answers. You've never voted. Please spend some time with the [faq] learning how to give back to the community.

Comment: @Vitaly Put this as an answer under your question.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, `SetDescription()` perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a description. It is not a title.

Comment: Have you tried it? Could you add the code you have so far to your question?

Comment: Yes, i did. Here is an example: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969393.aspx#Shellink_Item_Identifiers)

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut's display name is a name of its link file (without extension). Thanks, guys.